# How to delay response in Node/Koa?

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

I am trying to use setTimeout to delay returning a response in Node. With the following code, the activateAccount api gives a 404. It logs "in setTimeout" but nothing ever gets returned. Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
module.exports.activateAccount = function *() {
    this.body = { ok: false };

    if(this.session.otherMembershipFound){
        console.log("in otherMembershipFound");
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("in setTimeout");
            this.status = 200;
            this.body = { ok: false, result: { 
                    ok: false
                    , result: null
                    , message: "We encountered one or more validation errors."
                    , debug: "Other Membership Found"
                } 
            };
        }, 3000)    
    } else {}
}
```

As per the Promise explanation below, I tried the following but I am struggling with what the correct implementation should be.

```
if(this.session.otherMembershipFound){
    console.log("in otherMembershipFound");
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("after");
        this.status = 200;
        this.body = { ok: false, result: { 
                ok: false
                , result: null
                , message: "We encountered one or more validation errors. Please check the entered data and try again. For assistance please call 1 (800)617-3169."
                , debug: "Other Membership Found"
            } 
        };
    }, 3000)    
} else {
```

With that I get this error

```
(node:21796) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot remove headers after they are sent to the client
at ServerResponse.removeHeader (_http_outgoing.js:540:11)
```

Answer (score 1):

When a Koa middleware function returns, koa considers the request *done* and will send back what it can.

However, if the Koa middleware function returns a promise, it will postpone this until the promise is resolved.

So the trick to letting koa *wait* is to return a promise, and resolving the promise only when you are fully done.

P.S.: The asterisk (`*`) makes me suspect you are using Koa 1, or you've followed a tutorial about Koa 1. Usually if you see `*` and `yield`, you will want `async` and `await` instead.

Comment: Can you help me with the syntax of this?

Comment: Your code is a step in the right direction, but `this.status` probably doesn't make sense. Where is your `ctx` parameter? Things like `status` and `body` are typically set on `ctx` and `ctx.response`.

Comment: We are on an older version of Koa that doesn't use ctx. We are needing to update it but haven't gotten there yet.

Comment: I think even Koa 1 would have this. If not, I'm afraid I can't help you. I'm just not familiar enough with versions that old.

Answer (score 0):

You can use koa-delay library for doing this job. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-delay
Follow the documentation from library page.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't break anything but it didn't delay at all. The response still came back immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for necroposting, You can write you own sleep function and use in in the middleware like this:

```
async (ctx, next) => {
      const sleep = delay => new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, delay);
      });

      await sleep(1000);
      return next();
    },
```